# Signal and slot wrong value sending(Qt c++)

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlineedit, qlabel

I have written a small program to send data from one form(MainWindow) to another(Dialog) upon a button click. When the button is clicked the value written in the lineEdit of MainWindow is to be displayed on a label in Dialog form!

When I click the button a value is displayed on the label but it is not the same as the value entered in the line edit!
following are the respective codes in the 2 header and 2 cpp files!

MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

   signals:
   void sendIntData(int data);
   public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MainWindow();
}
```

MainWIndow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   Dialog *dialog1=new Dialog(this);

   dialog1->setModal(true);
   dialog1->exec();

   int o=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();


   connect(this, SIGNAL(sendIntData(int)),dialog1, SLOT(setIntData(int)));


   emit sendIntData(o);

}
```

Dialog.h

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public slots:
   void setIntData(int data);

   public:
   explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~Dialog();
}
```

Dialog.cpp

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::DIalog)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   QString value=QString::number(index);
   ui->label->setText(value);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
   delete ui;
}
void Dialog::setIntData(int data)
{
   index=data;
}
```

eg-When I click 3 and press the button I get a value 7237481! How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are showing int value which not initialized.

emit signal:

```
int o=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendIntData(int)),dialog1, SLOT(setIntData(int)));
emit sendIntData(o);
```

Show value:

```
void Dialog::setIntData(int data)
{
   ui->label->setText(QString::number(data));
}
```

Comment: @Kushan Peiris this should be helpful.

Comment: This answer can not be considered correctly. Because variable 'data' will never come here, if the sending code has not been changed correctly.

Comment: You are also writing to try to correct your choice but it will not happen. thank.

Comment: Read question comments and check timing then judge.

Comment: @J.Doe seems this code is a sample (pseudo code) and the problem was he update QLabel in constructor not in slot. for your concern i put declaration. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Replace connect and emit in `on_pushButton_clicked()`

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   Dialog *dialog1=new Dialog(this);

   dialog1->setModal(true);
   dialog1->exec();

   int o=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();

   connect(this, SIGNAL(sendIntData(int)),dialog1, SLOT(setIntData(int)));

   emit sendIntData(o);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If only once we convey our dialogue, the importance of signal and slot is not necessary.
It is possible to give this value to the constructor or to do the initialize function and to give it the values.

```
//way 1:
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    Dialog *dlg = new Dialog();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(SendData(int)), dlg, SLOT(slotData(int)));
    emit SendData(ui->lineEdit->text().toInt());
    dlg->exec();
}

void Dialog::slotData(int arg1)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(arg1));
}

//way 2:
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    Dialog* dlg = new Dialog(ui->lineEdit->text().toInt());
    dlg->exec();
}

//way 3:
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "QDebug"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::initialize(int value)
{
     ui->label->setText(QString::number(value));
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    Dialog *dlg = new Dialog();
    dlg->initialize(ui->lineEdit->text().toInt());
    dlg->exec();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post answers without explanations

Comment: The Dialog should be allocated in MainWindow::MainWindow once and then you use show() and hide(). You currently allocate memory on each click which is not even the parent of MainWindow.